# IE8 failed to download zip file from Document Library

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-online, internet-explorer

I cannot download zip file from any Document Library on SharePoint Online 2013 when using IE8. It always get error:

> Unable to download aaa.zip from company.sharepoint.com
>
> Unable to open this Internet site. The requested site is either
>   unavailable or cannot be found. Please try again later.

When using other browsers (IE11, Chrome), file can be download normally.

This even happen when I enter direct link to address bar of IE8 and hit Enter.

Comment: is this behaviour on one PC, can you try on differnt machine using IE 8? sometime resetting IE settings fix or clear the temp folder. http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/error-message-unable-to-open-this-internet-site/758f7a64-b081-4981-814f-9a7a53434fb8

Answer (score 1):

When Internet Explorer communicates with a secure Web site through SSL, Internet Explorer enforces any no-cache request. If the header or headers are present, Internet Explorer does not cache the file. Consequently, Office cannot open the file. Web sites that want to allow this type of operation should remove the no-cache header or headers.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415370/ie-unable-to-download-from-unable-to-open-this-internet-site-the-request

Comment: So could we have a solution to fix the Document Library on SharePoint Online? Modify `Cache-Control`?